# Yii - rule allowEmpty for model

Tags: php, validation, yii

I have a standard model `LoginForm`, which uses a CAPTCHA to login. Anyway in some page i need login without captcha. For this i added `public $useCaptcha = true;`. When it's `false`, CAPTCHA don't need. I also added one rule:

```
array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest || !CCaptcha::checkRequirements() || !$this->useCaptcha)
```

But my rule doesn't work. It's return always false. As solution i'm use `beforeValidation` function:

```
protected function beforeValidate()
{
    if(!$this->useCaptcha)
    {
        $this->getValidators()[4]->allowEmpty = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But this is not good decision. Why `allowEmpty` rule return `false`?

Comment: have you tried using scenarios , eg on=>login empty=>true

Comment: @Gunnit when i use `array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'on'=>'useCaptcha')` instead of rule in top - i always get error - "The verification code is incorrect." For set scenario i use `protected function beforeValidate()
    {
        if($this->useCaptcha)
        {
            $this->setScenario('useCaptcha');
        }
        return true;
    }`

Comment: try looking at this => http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/21561-captcha-custom-validation/ , i think is simillar to your issue

Comment: Thanks for link. Unfortunately i could not use standard rules, but i find better decision.

Answer (score 0):

"public $useCaptcha = true" is a variable class, you need to set one validator for it !

Eg. Add this rule :

```
array('useCaptcha', 'safe', 'on'=>''),
```

After that you will able to change "$this->useCpatcha" value.